# Screen resolution change notification message?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a WTL app running and would like to know when the screen resolution has changed.  The most likely candidate would appear to be `SPI_SETWORKAREA` sent via the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message but I wondered if this is the correct message to use.  This has to work on XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the better mouse trap.

Comment: For an example of how to handle this message, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985093/18529