# Detect when new display is connected

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an application that requires two displays: one for the control panel, the other for the output. What I have is this: if there's only one display, the application shows both forms on it but if there are two, the output form goes to the other.
The problem is that this only happens when the application is started. In other words, if the application is already running before the second display is connected, nothing happens unless the user sends the output to the new display manually (assuming they know how to do it).
What I want is that when a new display is connected, the output form is automatically sent to it even while the application is running. I think it has to do with polling a port in a thread but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help with how to do it? If there is a better solution, I'll gladly welcome it.

(I would have provided some part of the code but I'm typing this from a phone)

Comment: You could create a polling loop to regularly check for a new display in a background thread/background worker. E.g. read the [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) property and execute some code if it becomes `> 1`.

Comment: That's what I thought of but I need code on how to do it. I have problems with writing threads. Can u help?

Comment: You can use this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.100).aspx And you can use the BackgroundWorker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Davio Thanks for the link. But from what I read there, it seems backgroundworker is meant to carry out long running tasks that occur due to user input. I just want something that works like this: checks if the display is connected, sends the output and, maybe, destroys itself.

Comment: Your program should get a message from Windows when there is another screen, I think. [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be a candidate.

Comment: @Joey U may be right about windows sending a message. WM_DISPLAYCHANGE is about change in display resolution and I don't think adding a new screen is the same as changing the resolution of the old one. I'll try to find out the message sent for a new display. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lookie here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx

There's an example which should help you. Try something like this:

```cs
public class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
        const uint WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 0x007e;
         // Listen for operating system messages. 
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
                // The WParam value is the new bit depth
                uint width = (uint)(m.LParam & 0xffff);
                uint height = (uint)(m.LParam >> 16);
                break;                
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WndProc` and `Screen.AllScreens.Length`:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1) //example
        {


        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

*More information:*

- `WndProc`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx
- `Screen.AllScreens`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can include a timer which checks e.g. every 2 seconds if the number of screens is more than one. The code could look like this:

```
timer_tick()
{
    if(Screen.AllScreens.Length >= 2)
    {
        //run code to use the second screen
    }
}
```

It´s easy to use for beginners in C#.

Comment: This is wrong! You do not have to include any timer!

Comment: This isn't wrong. It works. You do not have to include any timer, thats right, but please be more specific, what a code without a timer would look loike

Comment: @sergiol Is it better like this?

Comment: In my testing Screen.AllScreens didn't get updated until I restarted the program, I'm pretty sure this won't work