# Retrieve Desktop Resolution before Remote Desktop is Connected

Tags: c#, screen-resolution, rdp

I have an application running that is scaled to match resolution of a monitor. It is written to adjust to any monitor resolution. If I establish connection using remote desktop and then start the application, it picks up the Remote Desktop's resolution (its settings) instead of the original desktop resolution.

Question is - how to retrieve the original resolution settings (the ones that are restored after remote connection is closed)?

Current settings are retrieved using: `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize`

Comment: Can you clarify the sequence of events?  Are you launching the application IN a remote desktop session?

Comment: 1. The application starts and forms are resized to match screen resolution. 2. Remote session is established and restarts the application. 3. The application is now started and resized based on the remote settings, not the original resolution.

Comment: Sucks that return posts the comment, doesn't it? >.<

Comment: You may be better off to listen for [resolution change notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983111/detect-when-new-display-is-connected/11985093#11985093) instead... you don't need RDC to change resolution - change of local resolution (or drag to other monitor) should behave as bad if you fix size based on current first monitor size...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I don't recommend shutting down an application and restarting it when you switch monitors.  Ouch.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - not the case, the application is accessed from many different PC's, with different resolutions. It maybe restarted, which will inevitably cause application to mismatch its original resolution settings.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - if the application is closed, how will it listen for resolution change notification?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - It will not.  I mean to say the OP commented that the second step in his process is "Remote session is established and restarts the application.  3. The app is now started and resized...".  If changing the resolution requires application restart then the user needs to modify his workflow first so it doesn't require restart.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - got it... removed that comment.

Comment: Just to clear things a little, the resolution change is not needed at all, the remote session causes it when other users restart the application.

Comment: I'm not sure now what is your problem - user connects to machine with RDC, starts application and you want program to be sized to fit physical screen of that machine even if user will never see than native resolution? Than you solution to pick size of a monitor seem to be fine...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - Yes, that is what I need, however, my method resizes the application to user's setting of remote desktop, which is not what I want. The application is publicly displayed on a screen, which means its resolution should always be relative to its own screen.

Comment: You are right... You probably have to dig into PInvoke of [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) to potentially get display resolution for monitor attached to physical adapter... (This just a guess, I'd not go this route - but it look like you must have fixed size irrespective what current screen resolution for current user is, so low level methods are probably ok).